# Can you retry a failed Turn Undead attempt?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, cleric, undead

In AD&D if you tried to turn undead and failed to roll high enough to turn that hit die of undead, you could not retry turning that same undead. In 3.5 I don't see that restriction. So can you retry a failed turning attempt?

Comment: Just FYI (my opinion) in general I feel 3.5 is pretty good about telling when an action can't be performed a second time.  See for example the Krenshar's scare (http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/krenshar.htm).  If it doesn't say anything generally it means you can do it again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can, up to your limit of turning attempts in a day (the compensating factor that 1e did not have).  [See d20srd on Turning Undead](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#turnOrRebukeUndead).